# SmartGit log documentation?

Tags: git, smartgit

I would characterize myself as an intermediate Git user but, I confess, I find it remarkably difficult to comprehend the SmartGit log. For example, with the default coloring, does each color represent a specific branch (at least until that color is reused)? Do the columns represent different users?

I can't express strongly enough how much it would help to have a comprehensive explanation of the SmartGit log, one that dealt with both the basics and more complex scenarios. If something like that already exists, please tell me where it is and I will be so grateful. If not, would it be possible to provide that information in the docs or in a blog post?

If nothing else, perhaps you could answer my two questions above.

Answer (score 2):

> does each color represent a specific branch (at least until that color is reused)?

Yes

> Do the columns represent different users?

No: one column per branch

See this example:

[image: http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/img/galery/hg-log.png]

<sup>SmartGit 6.5</sup>

Each line mentions the name of the branch the little 'o' refers to.
The official doc is [**Commit Graph**](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/documentation/latest/?page=commits#aboutCommits)

Comment: How do you have this "Branch" column? I do not see it in the list when I right-click on the header.

Comment: @Mikhail What version of SmartGit are you using?

Comment: The latest - SmartGit 7 rc 1 #5148

Comment: @Mikhail are you in the "commits" view?

Comment: Yes, I am. Please, see the image in the corresponding chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87746/smartgit-branch

Comment: @Mikhail, I noticed exactly the same thing: there is no option to display a branch column in the latest version of SmartGit. Perhaps what makes the column usage so confusing is the frequency with which colors are reused in SG. I'm looking at an area of our log where, within 15 commits, representing about 24 hours, a column that was one color, switches to another color for about 10 commits, and then switches back to the original color. Anyway, I suspect the docs that VonC mentions will help and I thank you both.

Comment: @RobOaks Don't hesitate to contact SmartGit's support at smartgit@syntevo.com, they are very attentive. I've already reported dozens of bugs, suggestions and questions, each of them answered within a day or so.

Comment: @Mikhail, I do not doubt the veracity of your statement--SmartGit is an exceptionally well-conceived and well-executed product. It has the distinct smell of software created by people who care deeply about the quality of what they deliver.